# UBUNTU 18.04 Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:00:04.0: Unknown Error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

My gpu stopped working all of a sudden.

nvidia-smi -a
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:00:04.0: Unknown Error

cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.100  Fri May 29 08:45:51 UTC 2020
GCC version:  gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
CUDA Version 10.2.89

Similar questions suggest it may be a problem with Vmware. Not sure where to find the vmx files.
Not sure also where to start debugging this problem.
Thank you for your help.